# Select columns from 4 tables

Tags: select, sql-server-2012, multiple-columns

First thing, I am totally new to SQL, saw some tutorials, vidoes, tried searching but didn't find what I needed. I know it has asked before, but I couldn't find it.

What I need to find is basically like

Select Company.Name, Programmer.Name, Manager.Name, CEO.Name

where Company.City = Programmer.City = Manager.City = CEO.City

like select all of them who are from London.

EDIT: Tried doing this with 2 tables only, code as below, but I'm getting an error

The multi-part identifier "Company.Name" could not be bound.

```
SELECT Company.Name
    FROM Company Cm
    INNER JOIN Programmer Pg
        ON Cm.City = Pg.City
    WHERE Cm.City = 'London'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the alias you assigned:

```
SELECT Cm.Name
    FROM Company as Cm
    INNER JOIN Programmer as Pg
        ON Cm.City = Pg.City
    WHERE Cm.City = 'London'
```

You can extend the pattern:

```
select Cm.Name, Cm.Address,
  Pg.Name, Pg.Address,
  Mgr.Name, Mgr.Address
  from Company as Cm inner join
    Programmer as Pg on Pg.City = Cm.City inner join
    Manager as Mgr on Mgr.City = Cm.City
  where Cm.City = 'London'
```

This will return rows where all of the tables have matching data, i.e. `City`.

If you want rows returned where some data may be missing, for example a manager but no programmer, then you would use `left outer join` instead of `inner join`.  Using `outer join` requires some care in constructing the `where` clause to avoid converting the joins from outer back to inner.

```
select Cm.Name, Cm.Address,
  Pg.Name, Pg.Address,
  Mgr.Name, Mgr.Address
  from Company as Cm left outer join
    Programmer as Pg on Pg.City = Cm.City left outer join
    Manager as Mgr on Mgr.City = Cm.City
  where Cm.City = 'London'
```

Comment: Same thing, same error.
Edit: My mistake, that fixed it, why did it give me the error on my code?

Comment: One last thing, how would I add a third table to that query? If I use another inner join like inner join manager as Mg on cm.city = mg.city it will check only for both manager and company, disregarding programmer, so this would be like an "Or", not an "And"

Comment: When you create an alias for a table in a query you can refer to columns in the table without specifying the source, e.g. `Name`, (as long as the column name is unique), or by using the alias, e.g. `Cm.Name`.  You cannot use the table name.

Comment: @Legjendat - I added an example with outer joins.  Try fiddling about with changing the `on` and `where` clauses.  What happens if you change the second `on` to `on Mgr.City = Pg.City`?  Or add to the `where` an extra `and Pg.Name > `Alice'`.  Seemingly innocent changes make a big difference with outer joins.

Comment: Thanks so much man, you were very clear in your answers, you would have made a much better teacher than my current one :)

Comment: Lol I just want to say thanks again, I finally got it, I was rushing, and I was getting incorrect results because I needed to add another condition before the inner join like pg.company = cm.name and so on, you have no idea how valuable this was to me, so TY.